# PHP Pagination script is not working

Tags: pagination, paging

I have a problem with my pagination script. I have two links on one category:

link 1: abc.com/category.html

link 2: abc.com/category-p2.html

My php script is:

```
$pagelink = 'abc.com/category';    
if($pages > 1)
{ 
   $pagination = '';        
   $pagination.= '<ul class="paginate">';
   for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++)            
    {
     $pagination .= '<li><a href="'.$pagelink.'-p'.$i.'.html">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
   $pagination .= '</ul>';
}
```

I want that: if $i=1, $pagelink is: abc.com/category, not add -p$i before html prefix.
So my new code is:

```
$pagelink = 'abc.com/category';    
if($pages > 1)
{ 
   $pagination = '';        
   $pagination.= '<ul class="paginate">';
   for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++)            
    { 
       if($i=1)
         {$pagination .= '<li><a href="'.$pagelink.'.html">1</a></li>';}
       else
         {$pagination .= '<li><a href="'.$pagelink.'-p'.$i.'.html">'.$i.'</a></li>';}
    }
   $pagination .= '</ul>';
}
```

But it's seem that it is not working. 
Please help me to fix this.
Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: "It seems that it is not working," how? Where it it going wrong, exactly? You can add some `var_dump()` statements to see what variables are set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate problem jumps out at me:

```
if($i=1)
```

should be:

```
if ($i == 1)
```